# Trying to generate a temporary txt file and then delete it

Tags: javascript, php, post

I have a site where I want a user to be able to download some data as a text file, without permanently saving the file on my server. The approach I'm trying is to  use JavaScript to send a POST,  using PHP to generate and save a text file. On   success, JavaScript will open that file in a separate window. After a few seconds delay, it will then send a POST with the file to delete.

I have most of it working, but for some reason, when I try to delete the file, I keep getting an error - No such file or directory.  I don't know why,  especially since using a test file to delete in the same directory works fine. Here's what I'm using on the javascript side:

```
////CREATE FILE
    function exportGroup() {

$.post("../Modules/Export_Mod/export_mod.php",
{ submit:'export',
  groupIndex: groupSelect.value,
  userRole: 'admin',
  serial: <?php echo $serial;?>
},
function(data,status){

//open created file in new window  
window.open("../Modules/Export_Mod/"+data);

removeExport(data);
});

};



 //////REMOVE FILE   
    function removeExport(filename) {
///After 1 second, send post to delete file
setTimeout(function() {
            $.post("../Modules/Export_Mod/export_mod.php",
            { submit:'removeExport',
                file: filename


            },
            function(data,status){  
            data;

            });
 }, 1000);

}
```

and my PHP:

```
//I'm creating the file successfully with this
...
$filename = $groupName."_group_export.txt"; 
$content = $header.$dataStr; 
$strlength = strlen($content); 
$create = fopen($filename, "w"); 
$write = fwrite($create, $content, $strlength);
$close = fclose($create);
```

But when I try to delete a second (or more) later using this:

```
if (($_POST)&&($_POST['submit']=='removeExport')){

$file = $_POST['file'];

unlink($file);   ///works when using an already-existing file in the same directory ... unlink('test.txt');

}
```

I get the error.    The first thing am wondering is if I'm approaching this the right way. If not, is there a better way to do it? And then the second thing I'm wondering is why I'm getting this error and what I need to change to make it work.

Comment: The code you've written is allowing any file to be deleted including script that has this code.

Comment: Is there another way to generate a txt file, allowing the user to download it, and then remove it?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to store any files at all.

Comment: can you please add the `errors` to your question ?

Answer (score 0):

I would check the server permissions to see if the php script that is running is able to delete the files that are created. If you are on a unix based script I would run the

```
ls -l /usr/var/
```

command on the directory that you are storing the files in, to see what permissions have been assigned to them.

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar sorts of things where a file is created and then deleted some time later, in my case 24hrs. But what I did was to set up a cron job to find the files that are older than a period of time and then delete them. That way I don't have to depend on the browser to post back a delete request.

Another option is to set up a custom session handler that deletes files associated with the session upon close of the session. Though that may leave things lying about if the user doesn't officially log out.

Or you could keep the file data in CLOBs on MySQL and then set up a query that kills them after a period.

Or if you feel like using Cassandra, you can set a TTL on a row and it will magically disappear.

Don't get locked in to operating system files. You control what data is provided by your pages, so if you want to send back data and call it a "file" the user will never know that it is actually a database entry.